# Video driver for an Acer 5253

Tags: 10.10, drivers, xorg, acer

I installed 10.10 on an Acer 5253-BZ684.  The dimensions are not optimal and I cannot change the generic unknown setting created during the install.  What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check for any proprietary drivers:
`System > Administration > Hardware Drivers` is how it shows up on 10.04.  Typically these issues are because some proprietary driver is needed but not installed.